# How can I draw a histogram from a nested list?

Tags: plotting, charts

I have a nested list of the form

```
list= {{1,1,1},{1,2,3},{1,1,1}}
```

How can I plot a histogram that tells me how often each number pattern appears in my list?

For example, `{1,1,1}` occurs two times and `{1,2,3}` occurs one time etc.

Comment: A histogram needs an order imposed over the x axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Tally` to count the occurrences of each element and use the result in `BarChart` :

```
list = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 1}};
BarChart[Labeled[#2, #1] & @@@ Tally[list]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, use `BubbleChart3D` with the bubble sizes representing the counts:

```
BubbleChart3D[Flatten /@ Tally[list]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]